# Use of Wrapper class increases size of object?

Tags: java, oop, wrapper

Simple question may be..
Suppose I have class A contains two primitive integers (int) and class B contains two Wrapper class Integer.
which object's size will be greater? A or B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instances of these classes will typically be the same size.  On most JVMs, it uses 32-bit references so your wrapper with two 32-bit values (int or references) will be the same, about 24 bytes in total on a 64-bit JVM.

In a 64-bit JVM, the default header size is 12 bytes, the references will be 32-bit with Compressed Oops, and an 8 byte alignment will be a total size of 24 bytes.

```
Header - 12 bytes with 64-bit class references
int or ref - 4 bytes
int or ref - 4 bytes
align to multiple of 8 - +4 bytes
==========
Total - 24 bytes
```

If the references are 64-bit (e.g. > 64 GB heaps) it will use 8 bytes per reference and the total size will be 32 bytes. However, if the alignment is 16 as well (for heaps between 32 - 64 GB) then the pair of `int` wrapper will also be 32 bytes.

If you are concerned about total space consumed, and the Integer is not cached i.e. is a new Integer, the total space can be a further 16 bytes per Integer.  If the Integer is cached, it doesn't use any more space.

Comment: @TheLostMind The classes will also typically be the same size, but that is not the question ;)

Comment: How come?..  Do you mean *Class objects*?

Comment: And why will the instances' size be *24* bytes?. :P.

Comment: @TheLostMind You need to add the object header and take object alignment into consideration.